# Django Logging Rotating files not working

Tags: python, django, logging, ubuntu-14.04

So i am having some issues with Django logging when it gets to the `maxBytes` size. Basically when that happens the file does not seem to rotate and create a new file.

Someone told me this could have something to do with the writing permissions of the server but i am not sure how to set that properly so that django is able to create a new log file when the old one is full.

my settings:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': "[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s",
            'datefmt': "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S"
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '[%(levelname)-7s] %(asctime)s - %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        },
        'console': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler'
        },
        'boom_file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'maxBytes': 1024*1024*10,  # 10 MB
            'backupCount': 10,
            'filename': '/var/log/boom.log',
            'formatter': 'simple'
        },
        'binglaw_crawler_file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'maxBytes': 1024*1024*10,  # 10 MB
            'backupCount': 10,
            'filename': '/var/log/boom-binglaw-crawler.log',
            'formatter': 'simple'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'boom': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'boom_file'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
        'boom.binglaw_crawler': {
            'handlers': ['binglaw_crawler_file', ],
            'propagate': False,
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    }
}
```

i noticed my other log celeryd seems o be rotaing just fine.. isnt that strange?

```
-rw-r--rw- 1 root          root          10485721 Aug 18 12:12 boom-binglaw-crawler.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root          root            403506 Nov  8 23:42 boom-celeryd.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root          root             20201 Oct  2 12:47 boom-celeryd.log.1
-rw-r--rw- 1 root          root           1049478 Oct  1 18:49 boom-celeryd.log.2
```

UPDATE:

i am getting this error when i try to run the manage command that creates the log file

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/handlers.py", line 77, in emit
    self.doRollover()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/handlers.py", line 142, in doRollover
    os.rename(self.baseFilename, dfn)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Comment: have you tried `disable_existing_loggers': True`? And is your Django running under `root` or having write permission?

Comment: i am going to try it now @Anzel

Comment: yeah DJango is running under root @Anzel

Comment: it's the write permission of your log file, try this: `chmod 777 boom-*` and see if it fixes the problem. Then we will set a lower permission rights

Comment: @Anzel i already tried chmod 777 and nothing. i have updated my code above with the permission denied error i am getting when i try to run the command on production

Comment: when you run your `manage` command, are you sure you're running under `root` group?

Answer (score 7):

When using the 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler' in Django logging, I had this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\logging\handlers.py", line 73, in emit
    self.doRollover()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\logging\handlers.py", line 176, in doRollover
    self.rotate(self.baseFilename, dfn)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\logging\handlers.py", line 116, in rotate
    os.rename(source, dest)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'log.txt.1'
```

This error was happening to me because when I start Django, it seems to start 2 different processes.  Both processes setup logging, which means both get a handle to the same LOGGING files defined in 'settings.py' config file.

I added this line to my settings.py file, right before I set my LOGGING variable.

```
print("Initializing LOGGING in settings.py - if you see this more than once use 'runserver --noreload'")
```

If you start the app with 'manage.py runserver **--noreload**' parameter, it may cure your file contention issue.

Comment: Good catch. Do you think there's any other way to handle this situation without having to use `--noreload`?

Comment: Would be also intereset in a different way. Also the --noreload option still yields the error for me running on windows 10, django 2.1

Answer (score 4):

One solution, which currently works for for me, was to use `'delay': True` for the handler ids that write to files (the `RotatingFileHandler` in my case). This creates the files only when the first `emit()` is called from the loggers, and my understanding is that the thread contention between the main thread and the autoreload thread (which is the cause of the error) seems not to exist at that point.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using a TimedRotatingFileHandler in combination with the local development server.

My solution which does not supply the `--noreload` flag is

```
if os.environ.get('RUN_MAIN') == "true":
    logging.config.dictConfig(LOGGING)
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
else:
    logger = logging.getLogger('root')
```

It is not 100% clean as the second process gets a different logger but for me i wanted to have the auto reload feature enabled.