# Setting a Log file max size in Django project

Tags: python, django, logging

I have this configuration in my project:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'debug.log'),
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

Now its size grows uncontrollably. **Is there a way to control a size of `debug.log` file?** What is the best way to operate with log files in Django projects?
 I have found [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24505145/how-to-limit-log-file-size-in-python?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) but I am not calling python logger directly.

Answer (score 17):

What you're looking for is Python's [`RotatingFileHandler`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#rotatingfilehandler).

Use this in your `'handlers'`

```
'file': {
    'level': 'WARNING',
    'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
    'filename': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'debug.log'),
    'backupCount': 10, # keep at most 10 log files
    'maxBytes': 5242880, # 5*1024*1024 bytes (5MB)
},
```

When I tried I got `PermissionError`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27080774/5599955) explains how to handle it. EDIT: This happens when you use django's development server to run it. Shouldn't be a problem in other cases.

Comment: I'm tring this solution in my poroject